# Bibliography as Chapter in Table of Contents is not working

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, chapters

I added the following package:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\small\upshape}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}
```

This however results in my Bibliography (References) shown as section instead of chapter in the table of contents. Does anyone know why this is the case?
I already tried

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

This adds References as Chapter, but the Refernces as Section still remains.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: As always on this site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal) example others can copy and test as is. You only provide a sniplet wgere we have to guess the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bases on your first question and the given code snippet above (better is to show us a complete short tex code building your bibliography and TOC so we do not have to guess what you are doing ...) first a solution for KOMA-Script only. Please see that I added option `bibliography=totoc,` for class `scrreprt` (needed for chapters or `scrbook`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt, 
  titlepage, 
  paper=a4, 
  twoside,
  bibliography=totoc, % <===============================================
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\small\upshape}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % <====================================================

\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}

\cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.
\urlstyle{same}
\bibliographystyle{plain} % <===========================================
\bibliography{\jobname} % <=============================================
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: KOMA-Script result]

Please see that the Bibliography is added to the TOC in chapter style (red arrows; compare with `Chapter one` above).

In your first question you are using `apacite`. Please note that you have to add option `[nosectionbib]` to the call of `apacite` to get the bibliography in TOC in chapter style:

```
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite} % <=================================
```

Please see the following complete mwe

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt, 
  titlepage, 
  paper=a4, 
  twoside,
  bibliography=totoc, % <===============================================
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite} % <=================================
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\small\upshape}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}

\cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.
\urlstyle{same}
\bibliography{\jobname} % <=============================================
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result with apacite]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your quick response. 
I changed

```
\usepackage{apacite}
```

to

```
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
```

and now it is working!